# LDA and regression

Tags: regression, discriminant-analysis

Say we have a classification problem with $k$ classes, an $N\times p$ matrix $X$ whose rows are predictors and an $N\times k$ indicator response matrix $Y$. The problem is to show that LDA on $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ is equivalent to LDA on $X$.

Algebraically this is trivial if $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ is square and invertible, but of course this need not be the case. I have a rough intuitive understanding of why this should work but the details elude me.

Let $B=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ and let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of the input space of $p$-vectors. LDA on an input $x$ is determined by the quantity
$$\log\frac{P(G=k|X=x)}{P(G=\ell|X=x)}=\log\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_\ell}-\frac12(\mu_k+\mu_\ell)\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_\ell)+x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_\ell)$$
(If my notation requires explanation let me know.) Using the transformation specified in the problem changes $\Sigma^{-1}$ to $B(B^T\Sigma B)^{-1}B^T$, which is simply $\Sigma^{-1}$ when $B$ is square and invertible. In general it won't be though. But will the resulting scalar quantity be the same anyway?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "LDA on $X$," which makes no reference to any responses at all, and by the similar phrase "LDA on $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$," which--since it is the projection of the responses into a subspace--makes no reference to any predictors beyond the space they span?

Comment: @whuber In both cases the response matrix is $Y$. The $i$th row is classified according to the position of the $1$ in the $i$th row of $Y$.

Comment: @whuber and the rows of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^{-1}Y$ are in natural correspondence with the rows of $X$, the predictors, given that they are the output of a linear regression of $Y$ on $X$, so they approximate the indicator response for the corresponding row of $X$.

Comment: I completed this problem, and my solution was __awful__ (so much that I'm sure I'm missing something myself).

One thing is that in fact, $\left(X^T X\right)^{-1}X^TY$ and your new $\Sigma^{-1}$ (with the $B$ terms) will _never_ be invertible, because $X^TY$ is _always_ a loss in rank if your data is centered and if $Y$ is an indicator response matrix (try and see why!). So you'll need something else.